# How to set Session Timeout in php?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, logout, session-timeout

I'm still new in PHP language and trying out on how to set Session Timeout, which ensure that when user log in to their account, it will limit to few minutes / 1 hour before the account got logout automatically when user log in too long. I refered to this link.

> http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/889606-setting-timeout-php-sessions

**index.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{ 
  session_start(); 
}

$timeout = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
/**
 * for a 1 minute timeout, specified in seconds
*/
$timeout_duration = 60;

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && ($timeout - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) > $timeout_duration) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = $timeout;
?>
```

**coupon.php**

```
<?php 
// error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);
session_start();
$timeout = 60; // Number of seconds until it times out.

// Check if the timeout field exists.
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    $duration = time() - (int)$_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($duration > $timeout) {
        // Destroy the session and restart it.
        session_destroy();
    }
}

// Update the timeout field with the current time.
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
// include ('sessionTimeout.php');

if( !isset($_SESSION["loginSuccess"]) ){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login failed!');</script>";
    die('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'login-redirect.php\'" />');
}
?>
```

**sessionTimeout.php**

```
<?php
function session_start_timeout($timeout=5, $probability=100, $cookie_domain='/') {
    // Set the max lifetime
    ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", $timeout);

    // Set the session cookie to timout
    ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", $timeout);

    $seperator = strstr(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)), "WIN") ? "\\" : "/";
    $path = ini_get("session.save_path") . $seperator . "session_" . $timeout . "sec";
    if(!file_exists($path)) {
        if(!mkdir($path, 600)) {
            trigger_error("Failed to create session save path directory '$path'. Check permissions.", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    ini_set("session.save_path", $path);

    // Set the chance to trigger the garbage collection.
    ini_set("session.gc_probability", $probability);
    ini_set("session.gc_divisor", 100); // Should always be 100

    // Start the session!
    session_start_timeout(60, 10);

    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + $timeout, $cookie_domain);
    }
}

?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

include('config.php');

foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
    if (strpos($key, $PROJECT_NAME) !== FALSE){
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}

$_SESSION[$PROJECT_NAME . 'logout'] = true;
session_destroy();

//print_r($_SESSION);
header('Location:' . $base_url . 'index');
?>
```

Am i missing out something? This is because my session timeout doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start a `Javascript` timer when the page loads and `redirect` the user to the `logout` page when the `timer expires`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "logout.php"; }, 60 * 60 * 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: where should i put that? :) @Rahautos

Comment: on page load @SitiNurainiYakob

Comment: which is under index.php? @Rahautos

Comment: noted. should i put it on all pages instead? But how should i make it automatically log out without making user to load the page? @Rahautos

Comment: If the user navigates to another page in the meantime the current timer would be discarded automatically and a new one started when that page loads.

Comment: As mentioned above, how should i show to the user that their account has been logged out when the session ended? Because as of now, when the session has ended, user is still prompted to coupon.php just that the data in coupon.php is not shown as usual. @Rahautos